# libgdx color class some colors are not working

Tags: libgdx

What is the current limitation of libgdx Color class.

I tried this RGB (123.0f, 188.0f , 219.0f , 1.0f), and my game only renders a white color.

are this colors not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value should be in 0...1 range otherwise it just will be clamped to 1

Comment: oh crap!. you should slap me as hard as you can. By the way, thanks